# How to change postion of textview in java the way i would in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

in xml my textview looks like this.

`

```
     android:layout_marginTop="248dp"
     android:text="hello world"
     android:textColor="#646464"
     android:textSize="200sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" />`
```

when i want to move my textview left or right i edit the value in the marginleft parameter and if i want to move my textview up or down i edit the margin top value. I want to be able to have this sort of control over the textview positioning in java. Can someone show me an example of code of this being done maybe using my textview as an example and moving the textview so that its new margin left is 160?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Create a layout param and set the margins
ie layoutParams.setMargins(160,0,0,0);

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the margin **( in dp )** of your `TextView` programmatically, try this  ( change the values of left, top, right , bottom with the value that you want to set as margin ):

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(left * density, top * density, right * density, bottom * density);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change TextView's LayoutParams programatically as follows:

```
TextView textView = /* your textview here ... */;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparam = 
       new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(textView.getLayoutParams());
lparam.topMargin = /* ... */;
lparam.rightMargin = /* ... */;
// or use lparam.setMargins() method.
textView.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id of textview in xml);

 tv.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);
//tv.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
 tv.setText( "Work");
 tv.setTextSize(17);
 tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

You can do this in java code.

Comment: -1 padding changes the starting position of its content, not changes the position of itself